# Git push Refspecs: `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/origin` vs `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`

Tags: git, refspec, git-refspec

Which push Refspec (Git) is correct? Or both are correct? What is the difference?

1. `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/origin/*`
2. `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`

I prefer (1) because it references remote name (origin), and I don't understand what (2) means (but I see it used in some manuals!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/origin/*`, `git push origin master` would be expanded to `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin/master`. It will create or update a branch named `origin/master` in the remote repository. It's valid, but `refs/heads/origin/master` would be ambiguous with `refs/remotes/origin/master`. In some situations, it might cause errors.

The 2nd is valid. With `remote.origin.push=refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`, `git push` is expanded to `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master refs/heads/dev:refs/heads/dev`, and `git push origin master` to `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.

Comment: Sorry very much! Of course I meant  `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/origin/*` for (1)

Comment: @CodeComplete With `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/origin/*`, `git push origin master` would be expanded to `git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin/master`. It will create or update a branch named `origin/master` in the remote repository. It's valid, but `refs/heads/origin/master` would be ambiguous with `refs/remotes/origin/master`. In some situations, it might cause errors.